# Laravel 5.1 - eager loading relationships to the same table executes multiple queries

Tags: php, laravel, eager-loading

I've got a model that has 4 relationships to the same table.

```
public function driver()
{
    return $this->belongsTo( Admin::class );
}

public function rejectedBy()
{
    return $this->belongsTo( Admin::class, 'rejected_by' );
}

public function reconciledBy()
{
    return $this->belongsTo( Admin::class, 'reconciled_by' );
}

public function updatedBy()
{
    return $this->belongsTo( Admin::class, 'updated_by' );
}
```

When I eager load all 4 relationships, the Laravel debugbar reports 4 queries to the `admin` table.

The method I use is:

```
$report = Report::find(1)
           ->with('driver', 'rejectedBy', 'reconciledBy', 'updatedBy')
           ->get();
```

Is there a way to group them together into only one query?

Comment: I think you have to make the joins manually in the querybuilder instead.

Comment: Where is the query?

Comment: @SanzeebAryal sorry, I'll edit the question to add that.

Comment: @Ethan22 that is 5 different queries and there is no way out with eager loading to group them together.

Answer (score 0):

Try the with method:

```
$adm = App\Admin::with('driver', 'rejectedBy', 'reconciledBy', 'updatedBy')->get();
```

Comment: That's the query I'm using. It executes a separate call to the `admin` table for each of the values in the `with` method.